# Identifying the location of the patch with the sprouting turtle

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am using the following condition to sprout a new turtle and it works.

```
ask one-of patches with [distancexy 0 0 < 30]
      [ if (random-float 1 < (beta * pm * 1000)) [sprout-parties 1 [initialize-party] ]]
```

What i want is to also record the patch co-ordinates on which the new turtle is created.

Comment: what do you mean "record"? record it where?

Comment: @SethTisue: What is meant was how to store the xy location of the patch in separate variable

Comment: A turtle variable? A patch variable? A global variable? A local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose each turtle owns an `origin` attribute.  Then you can just include in `intialize-party` the code `set origin (list xcor ycor)`.